# I can't find field locked in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have just installed the latest version of FOSUserBundle and after updating the data base I didn't find field locked in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between 2.0.0-alpha3 an 2.0.0-beta1, [a number of Methods and properties were removed](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Upgrade.md#200-alpha3-to-200-beta1) from FOS\UserBundle\Model\User - among them `$locked`